# Mono Dataset equivalence

Tags: web-applications, mono, dataset

I am trying to learn web development using Mono. Coming from ASP.NET background, I noticed that there is no "dataset" file when I am trying to add new file to the project.

In ASP.NET (Visual Studio IDE) you can add a dataset file that enable us to develop the connection to database, hence modelling it graphically. Is there such thing in Mono ?

By the way, I am using MonoDevelop.

Comment: You mean typed datasets?

Comment: I mean something like graphical dataset that contains table adapter & table. Where you can specifically declare a table with queries and add functions based on query. The best way to see this is by clicking right click on any web project in visual studio and select add new > choose dataset. It will generate an *.xsd file. Does this applicable in Mono too?

Comment: Design in VS, and then compile/edit on MonoDevelop should work fine, as xbuild can take care of the compiling. MonoDevelop does not come with the GUI candies that VS has. Of course, it is open source and you can write MD addons to achieve that goal.

Comment: @LexLi that is not really what I am looking for. So, there I guess there is no the GUI dataset thingy in Mono? (.xsd file)

Comment: Short answer : NO.But that should not prevent you from using Linux and Mono/C #. You can always use virtualization to launch Visual Studio from time to time when the need arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDevelop does not support creating a DataSet using a GUI. If there isn't any specific reason that you require creating a DataSet using the GUI then you could create DataSets in two different ways.

1. Using Code.

   ```
       DataSet ds = new DataSet ("Name");
       DataTable dt = new DataTable ("Name");
       dt.Columns.Add ("test", typeof (String));
       DataColumn dc = new DataColumn ("PK", typeof (int));
       DataColumn[] pk = new DataColumn[] { dc };
       dt.PrimaryKey = pk;
       ds.Tables.Add (dt);
   ```
2. Create DataSet files within your solution by adding XML files and typing out the XML for your DataSet manually.

Obviously these methods aren't as efficient as using the GUI designer in Visual Studio but they allow you to use MonoDevelop.